# Can anyone give me example code of _dupenv_s?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm using `getenv("TEMP")`, but I'm getting a warning telling me to use `_dupenv_s`.

I can't find an example of _dupenv_s on the net.

The docs read:

```
errno_t _dupenv_s(
   char **buffer,
   size_t *numberOfElements,
   const char *varname
);
```

But what buffer are they referring to? I only have varname. Wouldn't it be better to avoid using a buffer?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`_dupenv_s` is a Microsoft function, designed as a more secure form of `getenv`.

`_dupenv_s` allocates the buffer itself; you have to pass it a pointer to a pointer and it sets this to the address of the newly allocated buffer.

For example,

```
char* buf = nullptr;
size_t sz = 0;
if (_dupenv_s(&buf, &sz, "EnvVarName") == 0 && buf != nullptr)
{
    printf("EnvVarName = %s\n", buf);
    free(buf);
}
```

Note that you're responsible for freeing the returned buffer.

Comment: What is the alternative for GCC?

Comment: Just because _dupenv_s returns 0 doesn't mean the value exists. You still need to check if buf == NULL to verify whether it exists or not.

Comment: @MichaelIV `getenv` followed by a `strcpy` or if c++, calling `std::getenv` storing the result in a `std::string`.