# is there better way for making path through Environment variables in c/c++?

Tags: c++, env

is there better way for making path through Environment variables in c/c++ than this?

```
char *S1 = std::getenv("SystemDrive");
char *S2 = std::getenv("USERNAME");
strcat(S1,"\\\\Users\\\\");
strcat(S1,S2);
strcat(S1,"\\\\");
strcat(S1,"Documents");
```

Comment: ignoring the fact that `strcat` here invokes undefined behaviour, just use `std::stringstream`

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend getting the user profile directory something like this.

```
BOOL GetCurrentUserDir(LPTSTR lpszBuf, LPDWORD lpdwBuflen)
{
    HANDLE hProcessToken;

    if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_READ, &hProcessToken))
        return FALSE;

    if (!GetUserProfileDirectory(hProcessToken, lpszBuf, lpdwBuflen)) {
        CloseHandle(hProcessToken);
        return FALSE;
    }

    CloseHandle(hProcessToken);
    return TRUE;
}
```

I used this function like so:

```
WCHAR szLocalPath[MAX_PATH];
if (!GetCurrentUserDir(szLocalPath, &cchPath))
{
    //Handle the error
}
```

You can then append the rest of the path.

This encapsulates the specific environment variables and makes use of the Win32 API. This is more likely to remain portable over time.

Comment: What happens to `hProcessToken` if `OpenProcessToken` succeeded and `GetUserProfileDirectory` failed?

Comment: Good catch. Thanks will fix it. Cannot get the formatting right on iPhone, will need to fix it later

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use std::string?

```
std::string s1 = std::getenv("SystemDrive");
s1 += "\\\\Users\\\\" + std::getenv("USERNAME") + "\\\\Documents";
```

Answer (score 1):

One good way to concatenate multiple strings is to use `snprintf`:

```
char buf[0x10000];
int n = std::snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%s\\\\Users\\\\%s\\\\Documents", S1, S2);
if(static_cast<size_t>(n) >= sizeof buf)
    // Buffer is too small (if n > 0) or error
```

The fact that `snprintf` does not overflow the buffer and always zero-terminates makes unsafe functions `strcpy`, `strncpy`, `strcat` unnecessary.

Comment: You are not addressing the fact that he should not use getenv.

Comment: @Smash I see that Microsoft deprecated `getenv` in favour of non-portable `getenv_s`. However, `getenv` is a standard C function, and `std::getenv` has recently been introduced into C++. Microsoft's deprecation goes against C and C++ standards.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand what you need exactly. Is this to create paths from environment variables ? or to get proper paths of system directory ? in the latter case, you would better use the Win32 API, e.g.: `SHGetFolderPath` or `SHGetKnownFolderPath`.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <ShellAPI.h>
#include <KnownFolders.h>
#include <ShlObj.h>

int main()
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    TCHAR* path = 0;
    SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Documents, KF_FLAG_SIMPLE_IDLIST, NULL, &path);
    // use collected 'path' here
    CoTaskMemFree(path);    // free the TCHAR object allocated by SHGetKnownFolderPath
    return 0;
}
```

The above code retrieve the current user "My Documents" folder path.

Answer (score -1):

`std::getenv` is deprecated.

I would use something in the likes:

```
char*  wSystemDrive = nullptr;
size_t wSize = 0;

bool wFree = true;

if(_dupenv_s(&wSystemDrive,&wSize,"SystemDrive") != 0 || wSystemDrive == nullptr)
{
    wFree = false;

    wSystemDrive = "C:\\"; //or anything default you want to use
}

std::string wSysteDriveString(wSystemDrive);

if(wFree)
{
    free(wSystemDrive);
}

char*  wUSERNAME = nullptr;
wSize = 0;

wFree = true;

if(_dupenv_s(&wEnv,&wSize,"wUSERNAME") != 0 || wUSERNAME == nullptr)
{
    wFree = false;

    wUSERNAME = "User";
}

std::string wUSERNAMEString(wUSERNAME);

if(wFree)
{
    free(wUSERNAME);
}

std::string wPath = wSystemDriveString + "\\Users\\" + wUSERNAMEString + "\\Documents"
```

Note that you do not need 4 `\` (`\\\\`), only two (`\\`).

Comment: And why is that, this is exactly what the documentation suggests https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175774.aspx, and same thing as suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15916695/can-anyone-give-me-example-code-of-dupenv-s

Comment: Because it takes too many lines of code for such a routine task. It does not use RAII and hence is prone to leaks. For example, if the constructor of one of those `std::string` throws this code leaks memory. Such code is the reason C++ destructors came into existence - to do automatic cleanup to avoid leaks.

Comment: Who deprecated getting environment variables using `std::getenv`?